# A method declaring a mutable data structure as an output and returning an immutable one actually

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, immutability

Lately, I'm having a heated discussion regarding this issue.

Lets say I created this method in Java:

```
 public Set<String> getRich() {
    return ImmutableSet<String> ....;
 }
```

Whenever I see that in a pull request, I shout and try to explain why it is wrong. By doing that, I'm misguiding the consumers of my method by the promise that they will get a Set. This means they can remove or add elements. javac will happily compile that but **RuntimeException** will be thrown. Add to that, it is violating **"Liskov Substitution Principle"**.

Personally, I always do:

```
public ImmutableSet<String> getRich() {
    return ImmutableSet<String> ....;
}
```

This way, no one is going to shot himself in the foot.

One suggested approach is return ***Iterable***. I think this is bad, because the consumer of that method will lose the potential power of HashSet, HashMap or whatever (by not be able to call set.get(hash) ).

Another approach is - as a consumer - to create a copy of the output of **getRich()** method. But how are you going to be sure that the consumers will do that?

And of course, you have the folks who will stick to OOP design principles and say: "Always program to interfaces". To me - in this particular case - this is the worst option ever.

How would you deal with this case?

*(Off topic: This case is a perfect example how static typing might ensure correctness but it will never ensure rightfulness).*

Comment: The problem started where ImmutableSet implemented Set even though the implementation does not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Technically*, declaring the return type as `Set<T>` is not a violation of the LSP.

The documentation for [`Set<T>.Add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html?is-external=true#add(E)) explicitly states that implementations might throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.
Which means it's the clients responsibilities to check whether the set is mutable.

Now, whether making `ImmutableSet<T>` extend `Set<T>` was a good choice, that's debatable. 
I personally think it was a very bad choice - client code should not be littered with try/catches to find out whether a set is mutable. Furthermore, `Set<T>` does not even provide an `isMutable()` method to let clients perform the check easily! Having a separate interface for immutable collections would be a much cleaner design.

I personally would work around this *design flaw* and, as you suggested, declare the return type as `ImmutableSet<T>`.

The second part of your question is whether you should return `ImmutableSet<T>` or `Iterable<T>`: that really depends on what you think clients will expect from your API. Things to consider:

- Is your implementation likely to change? Do you think you'll ever need to change the business logic and return some other collection? If so, go with `Iterable<T>`;
- Do your clients explicitly expect an `ImmutableSet<T>`? If not, go with `Iterable<T>`;
- Otherwise, you might want to adhere to the [Robustness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle), which states "Be contravariant in the input type and covariant in the output type." In other words, choose the most abstract type possible for your arguments types, and the most specific type possible for your return types.

Comment: It's not a type error; but it is a violation of the LSP.

Comment: @larsmans Not really. If you program against the base class `Set<T>`, you'll have to check whether the set is mutable before trying to add any items - the documentation is clear on that. If I then give you a `HashSet<T>`, your code will work. If I then replace the `HashSet<T>` with an `ImmutableSet<T>`, your code will *still* work. The LSP holds. It's just a design flaw.

Comment: Ah! You're right, +1 (and deleted my answer). Java should have had an `ImmutableSet` as a super-interface of `Set`, [like Python does](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes).